# Problem finding button with Selenium on Python (not working)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I have the next code for a button, but I can't find it (to click it) with Selenium:

```
<button class="practice-button btn btn-primary btn-large theme-primary-button">OK, I'm ready! </button>
```

I've tried with

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='practice-button btn btn-primary btn-large theme-primary-button']")

browser.find_element_by_class_name('practice-button btn btn-primary btn-large theme-primary-button')

browser.find_element_by_class_name('practice-button')
```

but none of them has worked. Can you help me, please?

Comment: What is the full XPath for the button? You could also try searching for the button by its enclosed text, too, like this: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="OK, I'm ready!"]')`. The `normalize-space` function is a good practice because it strips whitespace from either side of the text.

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but I get:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[normalize-space()='OK, I'm ready!']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: The full XPath for the button appears to be:
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/button

Comment: I am not sure but have a feeling the punctuation in the button text is preventing that from working (probably the apostrophe in "I'm").

Comment: It's not the most elegant suggestion and isn't recommended if you can get anything else to work, but you can always select by the full XPath: `browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/button")`

Comment: I had already tried that, but didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried for finding a button with given classes and it worked. Depending on the context, there may be more efficient ways to find the button. Feel free to share the url or page code.

- xpath
- class_name
- css_selector

Given the page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <button class="practice-button btn btn-primary btn-large theme-primary-button">OK, I'm ready! </button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('file:///Users/jabbson/Projects/python/selenium-test/index.html')

button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//button[contains(@class, 'practice-button') and 
                                                  contains(@class, 'btn') and 
                                                  contains(@class, 'btn-primary') and 
                                                  contains(@class, 'btn-large') and 
                                                  contains(@class, 'theme-primary-button')]''')

button2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('practice-button')

button3 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.practice-button')

print('xpath:', button1.text)
print('class_name:', button2.text)
print('css_sel:', button3.text)
```

outputs:

```
xpath: OK, I'm ready!
class_name: OK, I'm ready!
css_sel: OK, I'm ready!
```

Comment: I tried all of them but the result is the same, it can not find it.

Comment: @IvánGM Then we need to see the page, there has to be something different between the page you are parsing and the example one I've created to test different ways to find the button, share the link to the page or the full html code.

Comment: How can I share you the code?

Comment: @IvánGM [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) would do it

Comment: Thanks, I pasted it there, but I don't know if it's the one you're looking for, because I didn't find how to copy the full code.

Comment: And the link to the paste?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/v7bBNxSU

Comment: Are you trying to click on a 'support' button?

Comment: No, it's a button to show the questions of a quiz (actually there are two buttons to click before showing the quiz)

Comment: Sadly, the only thing I see on the page is that support button (literally the blank page with one button), the rest is probably dynamically loaded

Comment: Oh, so is there no way to click the buttons in that case?

Comment: That I can't tell, all I am saying it is difficult for me to analyze the page, that would load (possibly the resource requires authentication). When you get the page with your driver, can you get the page source with browser.page_source, can you look up your button over there?

Comment: I got the source that way, here it is: https://pastebin.com/fD7Ey6rH

Comment: Do you see the button you are looking for in that source?

Comment: No, it's not there